# Server slow/freezing, wastes hard drives; tests fine: hardware issue?

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, memory, cpu, freeze

I have a personal server I run, and I'm upgrading to new hardware (an entirely new machine). I'm experiencing a number of bizarre happenings that feel like they could only be related to a hardware issue.

My setup:

- Supermicro X8DT6/X8DTE running version 2.0c BIOS
- 2x Intel Xeon X5680 CPU (at 3.33 GHz)
- 96 GB RAM (12x 8GB Hynix PC3-10600R)
- CoolerMaster v750 PSU

Testing:
I've tested the CPUs and Memory for errors and under a stress test, and both seemed to indicate all was healthy. All hard drives I've added first underwent a read/write test, and indicated a good SMART status.

Issues:

- I have been running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and there are points where it gets very slow (hours to load next dialog), and sometimes completely freezes up. Other times, it's blazing fast. This happens when running the OS installed, or from bootable disk. When it locks up, I'm unable to shut it down safely, and a hard reboot is the only option. In this state, it doesn't respond to SSH connections.
- I've placed multiple hard drives in this machine, and almost all have failed with I/O or SMART issues within days.
- I've had to reinstall the operating system many times due to data loss with rpool/zpool. (I didn't have anything of substance installed except docker.)

I'm curious if anyone has thoughts or a direction to start replacing hardware. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: "failed with I/O or SMART issues within days." - please be more specific.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Did those failed drives worked fine afterward in another computer? The machine that is having these problems is the old or the new one?

Comment: Did you try to replace the SATA cables? Update the BIOS? What tool are you using to confirm I/O smart errors? Need more information. Hardware cant usually cause drives to fail. So I am suspecting that you have a fault board that is misreporting the I/O status or you have some bad cables. Check the drives in another configuration.